# i am getting error while trying to configure razorpay

Tags: node.js, razorpay

can someone explain why i am getting this error

```
C:\Users\server\node_modules\razorpay\dist\razorpay.js:33
      throw new Error('`key_id` is mandatory');
      ^
Error: `key_id` is mandatory
    at new Razorpay (C:\Users\server\node_modules\razorpay\dist\razorpay.js:33:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\server\config\paymentConfig\razorPayConfig.js:3:18)

const instance = new Razorpay({`your text`
    key_id: process.env.RAZOR_PAY_KEY_ID,
    key_secret: process.env.RAZOR_PAY_KEY_SECRET,
});`your text`
```

if i use key_id directly i am not getting any error, but if use `process.env.RAZOR_PAY_KEY_ID` iam getting this error, but if i log  `process.env.RAZOR_PAY_KEY_ID` and `process.env.RAZOR_PAY_KEY_SECRET` i am getting proper values